# Windows 8 Java install is interrupted

Tags: windows-8, installation, java, uninstall, jre

Every time i attempt to install JRE 7u9 the installer gives me an error saying that java ran into an unexpected error please try installing later. Whenever i try I get the same error.
I attempted to uninstall Java 7u7 but the uninstalled quits in the middle, when i go to check what java version i have installed it gives me nothing. Please help, I desperately need JRE.

[image: 1]

[image]

Comment: You are going to have to provide us exact error codes.

Comment: No error codes are given it just closes itself.

Comment: Look into the temp directory usually log files are created there.

Comment: @Robert I can't seem to find the Temp directory on windows 8 :S

Comment: Win+R, %TMP% or %TEMP% should get you there (as long as the environment variables are defined correctly).

Comment: @Luqman Every user has his own temp directory in the local user profile appdata section. The Windows\temp dir is no longer used by regular programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed JRE 6u34 and it works fine, seems Windows 8 just doesn't like the new JRE.
Thanks for the help anyway guys.

Comment: It was answered four years ago, I simply removed a spelling mistake now. Please do have a look at the edit history before making random assumptions.